# Automatic Bootstrap Tabs in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, public-website, boot-strap

I'm trying to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606773/automatic-bootstrap-tabs) to a SharePoint public facing site.

The timer seems to be working as I'm getting errors in browser consoles at every interval but nothing is happening:

'TypeError: next.tab is not a function'

Any thoughts?

Comment: That means `jQuery.fn.tab` is `undefined`, which means the jQuery version you are working on does not have Bootstrap tabs appended to it. This could be the result of many things, such as not including the bootstrap script, or order of scripts, or having several versions of jQuery on the same page

Comment: Hmm, That seems to be the correct answer. I was using jquery 1.8.3 for the tabs and then jquery 2.1.1 for another slider element (cycle2).

So now only one or the other elements works on the site. Is there a way to include both jquery to make both features work correctly?

Comment: There are several ways, you might be able to use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). When it comes to SharePoint I usually just use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) (or browserify), although that might be a bit much

Comment: Actually, I got that wrong, it seems that I am using 2.1.1 which works great for the automatic tabs solution and then at the bottom of the age I use this library https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

 which is needed for the cycle2 slider to work.

I've never used no conflict before. Can I use it here do you think?

Comment: If you can stick with one version of jQuery that is the best. I'll just copy/move my top comment to question in order to snag a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

That means `jQuery.fn.tab` is `undefined`, which means the jQuery version you are working on does not have Bootstrap tabs appended to it. This could be the result of many things, such as not including the bootstrap script, or order of scripts, or having several versions of jQuery on the same page.

There are several ways to get around this, such as:

- Remove additional versions of jQuery.
- Check that your script is included, and included after jQuery.
- You might be able to use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).
- Use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) (or browserify).